# Where child model has two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Driver` model has_many `Workables`

How do I ask for a list of `Drivers` that have a `workable` where the `vehicle_id` is `x` and `has_vehicle` is `true`?

I *don't* want to include `Drivers` with two workables, one of which has the correct `vehicle_id`, and the other of which has `has_vehicle` == true

Ideally I probably want a scope for this.

I've tried the following, but it returns no records, in `Driver.rb`:

```
  scope :has_vehicle, -> (vehicle) {
    joins(:workables).
    where('workables.vehicle_id = ?', vehicle).
    where('workables.has_vehicle = ?', true) }
```

I could go for an approach like this, but it looks super slow:

```
   arr = []
   Workable.where(vehicle: x).where(has_vehicle == true).each do |e|
      arr += e.drivers.map(&:id)
   end
   @drivers = @drivers.where(id: arr)
```

Is the above fast if I use eager loading?

Comment: Is there any reason that you separated `vehicle_id` (integer) and `has_vehicle` (boolean) ? You could relay on the presence of the `vehicle_id` to determine if the `Driver` actually have a vehicle instead of storing it in the DB

Comment: Yes, the boolean provides new information. The drivers select vehicles that they would like to work with, and when whether the vehicle is provided by either themselves or the employer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a functional and fairly fast method:

```
driver_ids = Workable.where(driver_id: @drivers.collect(&:id)).where('vehicle_id = ? and has_vehicle = ?', params[:vehicle].to_i, true).collect(&:driver_id)
@drivers = @drivers.where(id: driver_ids)
```